# How to limit comment indentations to one level?

Tags: comments

When you reply on a comment then that replied comment is indented. When you reply on the reply comment then that comment is indented a bit more than the previous one and so forth.

I want to know whether or not it is possible to give all comment replies only one indention so that all comment replies are vertically aligned with each other? Can something like that be done?

Comment: If the answer was helpful to you, then consider accepting it. See »[What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)« and/or »[Why is voting important?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)«, more information about the [wordpress.se] model is available at the [help].

Answer (score 4):

This can be done, there is even a possibility to control this via the backend, just go to:

> → Settings → Discussion

And there under:

> → Other comment settings

You have the point:

> → Enable threaded (nested) comments | X | levels deep

Answer (score 1):

The 'problem' with the @Nicolai answer is that there is no reply link and therfore any notification plugins that rely on replies won't work. A tricky workaround is to use css (which is dependent on your theme's design) to counteract/remove the threaded indentation, and then, apply this code to allow many more depths of a thread. This way you can still have the reply links and use any reply notification plugins you **may** need.

```
// Set max comments depth to 99 on the discussion settings page
add_filter( 'thread_comments_depth_max', function( $max ){ return 99;} );
```